# How can I override a constant via a compiler option?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to define a constant in source code that can be overridden by a compiler flag? That is, something like setting a `#define` value in the C preprocessor with the `-D key=val` option to the compiler.

I have read about conditional compilation via the `#[cfg(...)]` attribute, but that only seems to support booleans. I want to allow the user to set the value of a constant during compilation.

Something like this:

```
#[from_cfg("max_dimensions")]
const MAX_DIMENSIONS: usize = 100_000;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can't define constants (read: `const` bindings) with a compiler flag. But you can use the [`env!` macro](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env!.html) for something similar. It reads some environment variable *at compile time*.

```
const MAX_DIMENSIONS_RAW: &'static str = env!("MAX_DIMENSIONS");
```

Sadly, this returns a string and not an integer. Furthermore we can't yet call arbitrary functions (like `parse`) at compile time to calculate a constant. You could use [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) to achieve something similar:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref MAX_DIMENSIONS: usize = MAX_DIMENSIONS_RAW.parse().unwrap();
}
```

Of course you should add proper error handling. If your user doesn't need to define the environment variable, you can use [`option_env!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env!.html).

With this approach, you can pass the setting at build time:

```
$ MAX_DIMENSIONS=1000 cargo build
```

Comment: Thank you! I had read about `env!` but somehow missed the "at compile time" part :-)

Answer (score 18):

Building on [Lukas Kalbertodt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37526735/155423), you can get the environment variable as a constant number with some extra indirection, namely by using a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html).

**build.rs**

```
use std::{env, fs::File, io::Write, path::Path};

fn main() {
    let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").expect("No out dir");
    let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("constants.rs");
    let mut f = File::create(&dest_path).expect("Could not create file");

    let max_dimensions = option_env!("MAX_DIMENSIONS");
    let max_dimensions = max_dimensions
        .map_or(Ok(10_000), str::parse)
        .expect("Could not parse MAX_DIMENSIONS");

    write!(&mut f, "const MAX_DIMENSIONS: usize = {};", max_dimensions)
        .expect("Could not write file");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=MAX_DIMENSIONS");
}
```

**main.rs**

```
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/constants.rs"));

fn main() {
    println!("The value is {} ({})", MAX_DIMENSIONS, MAX_DIMENSIONS + 1);
}
```

```
$ cargo run
The value is 10000 (10001)

$ MAX_DIMENSIONS=17 cargo run
The value is 17 (18)

$ MAX_DIMENSIONS=1 cargo run
The value is 1 (2)
```

Comment: Could you also use `cargo:rustc-cfg=KEY[="VALUE"]` (Enables compile-time cfg settings) and then drop the `include!` + creating a custom file abomination?

Comment: @KillPinguin I believe that all cfg values are inherently strings, so I'm not following how you'd get that to another type.