# What is the Rust equivalent of C preprocessor macros?

Tags: rust

In C world, when building external libraries, their behavior can be significantly customized at compile time by re-defining macros that are put in place by the library author.

If we look at SQLite's [Compile-time Options](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html), for example, one can pass the following options to the compiler to effectively change the values of constants defined in the library:

`-D SQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=2097152 -D SQLITE_DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS=3`

Is this possible to do something similar in Rust? Closest thing I've found is [Cargo features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section), but they only allow you to perform conditional compilation and not substitution of some predefined values at compile-time.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871967/what-is-the-difference-between-macros-and-functions-in-rust

Comment: Would something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3e3f3a43fa5481bc0dcfa3e018fda29) using [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) work? Or perhaps [`env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/std/macro.env!.html)?

Comment: Using `env` would be the more colloquial route I think, but would also involve parsing at runtime, probably with some `lazy_static`, but you could also write a `proc_macro` to parse it instead.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37526598