# Proper way to handle a compile-time relevant text file passed to a procedural macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a requirement to pass to a procedural macro either a text file or the contents of a text file, such that the procedural macro acts based on the contents of that text file at compile time. That is, the text file configures the output of the macro. The use case for this is the file defining a register map which the macro builds into a library.

The second requirement is that the text file is properly handled by `Cargo`, such that changes to the text file trigger a recompile in the same way as changes to the source file trigger a recompile.

My initial thought was to create a `static` string using the `include_str!` macro. This solves the second requirement but I can't see how to pass *that* to the macro - at that point I only have the identifier of the string to pass in:

```rust
use my_macro_lib::my_macro;
static MYSTRING: &'static str = include_str!("myfile");
my_macro!(MYSTRING); // Not the string itself!
```

I can pass a string to the macro with the name of the file in a string literal, and open the file inside the macro:

```rust
my_macro!("myfile");
```

At which point I have two problems:

1. It's not obvious how to get the path of the calling function in order to get the path of the file. I initially thought this would be exposed through the token `Span`, but it seems in general not (perhaps I'm missing something?).
2. It's not obvious how to make the file make `Cargo` trigger a recompile on changes. One idea I had to force this was to add an `include_str!("myfile")` to the output of the macro, which would hopefully result in the compile being made aware of "myfile", but this is a bit mucky.

Is there some way to do what I'm trying to do? Perhaps either by somehow getting the contents of the string inside the macro that was created outside, or reliably getting the path of the calling rust file (then making `Cargo` treat changes properly).

As an aside, I've read various places that tell me I can't get access to the contents of variables inside the macro, but it seems to me that this is exactly what the `quote` macro is doing with `#variables`. How is this working?

Comment: *I have a requirement to pass to a procedural macro either a text file* — [sounds how an XY problem starts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Like, all of this sounds like it should be a build script instead. E.g. [How do I generate a text file during compile time and include its content in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47217283/155423); [How to create a static string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32956050/155423); [How can I override a constant via a compiler option?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37528134/155423).

Comment: [A concrete example](https://github.com/avr-rust/avrd/blob/master/build.rs)

Comment: @shepmaster Having it as a build script rather breaks the ergonomics of having a macro invoked with the name of the file and requires every invocation to add a build script (I will have several for different parts of my code base). For comparison, I could always just have the whole contents of the text file in the argument to the macro, but then one loses syntax highlighting and so on when editing (it will be a YAML doc).

Comment: @Shepmaster Insofar as it's possible to do something else, it's not a strict requirement (so your XY problem point is reasonable), but I'm close to having very nice ergonomics on the library and I'm trying hard to see if I can actually implement fully what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out this is possible in essentially the way I was hoping with the stable compiler.

If we accept that we need to work relative to the crate root, we can define our paths as such.

Helpfully, inside the macro code, `std::env::current_dir()` will return the current working directory as the root of the crate containing the call site. This means, even if the macro invocation is inside some crate hierarchy, it will still return a path that is meaningful at the location of the macro invocation.

The following example macro does essentially what I need. For brevity, it's not designed to handle errors properly:

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;

use quote::quote;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream, Result};
use syn;
use std;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct FileName {
    filename: String,
}

impl Parse for FileName {

    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let lit_file: syn::LitStr = input.parse()?;
        Ok(Self { filename: lit_file.value() })
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as FileName);

    let cwd = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();

    let file_path = cwd.join(&input.filename);
    let file_path_str = format!("{}", file_path.display());

    println!("path: {}", file_path.display());

    let mut file = File::open(file_path).unwrap();
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();

    println!("contents: {:?}", contents);

    let result = quote!(

        const FILE_STR: &'static str = include_str!(#file_path_str);
        pub fn foo() -> bool {
            println!("Hello");
            true
        }
    );

    TokenStream::from(result)
}
```

Which can be invoked with

```rust
my_macro!("mydir/myfile");
```

where `mydir` is a directory in the root of the invoking crate.

This uses the hack of using an `include_str!()` in the macro output to cause rebuilds on changes to `myfile`. This is necessary and does what is expected. I would expect this to be optimised out if it's never actually used.

I'd be interested to know if this approach falls over in any situation.

Relevant to my original question, current nightly implements the [`source_file()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.source_file) method on `Span`. This might be a better way to implement the above, but I'd rather stick with stable. The tracking issue for this is [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54725).

Edit:
The above implementation fails when the package is in a workspace, at which point the current working directory is the workspace root, not the crate root. This is easy to work around with something like as follows (inserted between `cwd` and `file_path` declarations).

```rust
    let mut cwd = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();

    let cargo_path = cwd.join("Cargo.toml");
    let mut cargo_file = File::open(cargo_path).unwrap();
    let mut cargo_contents = String::new();
    cargo_file.read_to_string(&mut cargo_contents).unwrap();

    // Use a simple regex to detect the suitable tag in the toml file. Much 
    // simpler than using the toml crate and probably good enough according to
    // the workspace RFC.
    let cargo_re = regex::Regex::new(r"(?m)^\[workspace\][ \t]*$").unwrap();

    let workspace_path = match cargo_re.find(&cargo_contents) {
        Some(val) => std::env::var("CARGO_PKG_NAME"),
        None => "".to_string()
    };

    let file_path = cwd.join(workspace_path).join(input.filename);
    let file_path_str = format!("{}", file_path.display());
```

Comment: I tried this, and worked great until I used the crate containing the macro call as a dependency in another crate. then the cwd is the parent crate and the path is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the fragile bit. I guess one can come up with specific workarounds in response to specific crate requirements since it tends to be fairly well encapsulated.

Comment: Ultimately I was hoping to include a string from a file that needed parsing to use in the macro, and then assigning to a variable. Without the macro, beforehand I was using include_str! but the macro only sees that as tokens.
So in the end I have written a build script to generate the .rs file that contains the macro calls with the strings as literals passed to the macro.