# How to build a Rust library depended on a variable passed through command line?

Tags: rust

I have a library written in Rust that has a numeric constant inside.

```
pub const MY_CONST: usize = 32;

...

let arr: [i32; MY_CONST];

...
```

I want my library to be more flexible, so that I want to include it in other projects with different values of `MY_CONST`. Is there a way to build my project that depends on the library like this (or similar):

```
cargo build --MY_CONST=64
```

so this value from command line goes into `MY_CONST` in the library?

If not, maybe there is a better practice to reach this purpose in Rust?

```
// What is instead of get_from_command_line???
pub const MY_CONST: usize = get_from_command_line???("MY_CONST");
```

---

In GCC I am able to do similar thing using `-DMY_CONST=64` in compile command like this:

```
gcc -c mylib.c -DMY_CONST=64
```

so after that I can use `MY_CONST` anywhere in my code.

---

I also have viewed the question [How can I override a constant via a compiler option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526598/how-can-i-override-a-constant-via-a-compiler-option)

Unfortunately, it is not what I need. Because I need MY_CONST to be a **constant**, so I could be able to define static arrays in my library. The mentioned approach in the question doesn't allow it.

Comment: What's your usecase for this value? If you want to set it later, it's not a const, so to help you beyond that it would help to know the actual goal.

Comment: It is a size of static arrays actually. I would like them not to be dynamic. So I guess, I need MY_CONST to be exactly a constant in my code.

Comment: question have already been answered here. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526598/how-can-i-override-a-constant-via-a-compiler-option

Comment: @basic_bgnr Thank you for the link, it looks pretty well, but it doesn't work as I expect though. I tried `static ref MY_CONST = ...` as it's suggested there, but after that I can't define static arrays like this `let arr: [i32; *MY_CONST];`, I get the error `calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants`. In other words, it is not a way to get a **constant** from command line as I need.

Comment: @fomalhaut, did you look at shepmasters answer with the build script? That's the closest your going to get right now.